# test data with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mocking

Can anybody tell me how to save test data in tomcat webserver?I need to mock the data for ajax
application.But again i would ask if that is a good aproach?

Answer (score 0):

I test my webapps/webservices with Jakata JMeter.

[Jakarta JMeter - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMeter)

With JMeter you can test your applcation using JSON. It works fine, if the JSON Syntax is correct (a bit tricky that part)